# Get Window Position in HTA

Tags: window, position, hta

Can i get the current window position in HTA (HTML Application)? which is similar with `Me.Top` and `Me.Left` in VB6, but i want it get the pixels number.!?

Comment: With what language? With JS you can get the position of the topmost window with `top.screenLeft` and `top.screenTop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JS you can get the position of the topmost window with `top.screenLeft` and `top.screenTop`.

Comment: You can also do that with VBScript, I tried it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cool way to do it. It's sorta animated

VBScript

Add this to global variables

```
Dim IntervalMovingWindow
```

then add this OnLoad routine

```
Sub Window_OnLoad

  moveTo screen.availWidth/2-200 , screen.availHeight/2-100

  IntervalMovingWindow= Setinterval ("MoveTheWindow",100)

End Sub
```

Then Add this Routine for moving windows (animated style)

```
Sub MoveTheWindow

  Dim X,Y

  X=top.screenleft
  Y=top.screentop

  If X<=60 Then
    X=0
  End If

  If Y<=60 Then
    Y=0
  End If

  If X<>0 Then
    moveBy -20,0
  End If

  If Y<>0 Then
    moveBy 0,-20
  End If

  If X=0 And Y=0 Then
    moveto 0,0
   clearInterval IntervalMovingWindow
  End If
End Sub
```

This may not work if you have an excessively large border. in that case you may need to change `-20` in the `moveBy` to a larger negative number like `-30` and the `If {X or Y}=60` into a larger positive number like `If {X or Y}=80`

NOTE don't include the Braces '{}' they just mean that i am talking about both X and the Y conditionals.